# Spring JPA DTO projection and handling the nested projection with null values

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I am using class based projection with constructor expressions. here is a sample code form my work

```
@Query("select new com.core.data.category.CategoryDto(c.id,c.code,c.externalCode,c.seoMeta, c.createdAt, c.updatedAt,c.parent.code) FROM Category c where c.code = :code")
CategoryDto findCategoryByCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

This is how my `CategoryDto` look like:

```
public class CategoryDto implements Serializable {
 
private Long id;
private String code;
private String externalCode;
private SEOMeta seoMeta;
private CategoryDto parent;
private LocalDateTime createdAt;
private LocalDateTime updatedAt;
Map<String, LocCategoryDto> translation;

//constructor based on the requirement
}
```

This seems to be working fine except in one case where the property for the nested object is `null`. in my case the parent property can be `null` in case this is a root category but it seems using `c.parent.code` causing the issue and the entire object is coming `null`. Can someone help me with the following queries

1. Is there a way to handle this case using the same constructor expressions? I tried to look in to the doc but did not find the details.
2. I think other option might be using ResultTransformer (which will bind my code to specific JPA)but I did not find any information as how I can use it with Spring JPA.

**Update**
I even tried the option to use the `CASE` option but seems this is also not working for me as I am still getting the null entity (while data is available in the DB). Here is the updated code I tried

```
@Query(value = "select new com.core.data.category.CategoryDto(c.id,c.code,c.externalCode,c.seoMeta, c.createdAt, c.updatedAt, " +
            "CASE " +
            "WHEN  c.parent is NULL " +
            "THEN NULL " +
            "ELSE c.parent.code " +
            "END ) " +
            "FROM Category c where c.code = :code")
    CategoryDto findCategoryByCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

**Edit 2**
I had also tried even with join but that also seems not working for.

**Update**: I did a silly mistake.Was using the simple join and not left join which caused this issue.

Comment: Nitpick: using `ResultTransformer` will tie you to Hibernate. You are already tied to JPA by using it all over the place.

Comment: @JensSchauder first of all what does it mean by tying urself to hibernate or JPA ? Secondly, what's the harm in doing so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using left join

```
@Query("select new com.core.data.category.CategoryDto(c.id,c.code,c.externalCode,c.seoMeta, c.createdAt, c.updatedAt,parent.code) FROM Category c left join c.parent as parent where c.code = :code")
CategoryDto findCategoryByCode(@Param("code") String code);
```

Comment: Sorry..I forgot to update, I have already tried with join but seems not working for me case. I have updated my post as well.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi can you confirm you tried with left join and not just with join? could you share the code with the join trial?

Comment: You are right..I was trying for left join without using left and was looking for an issue else where :)

Comment: @tremendous7 can u help me understand why using simple inner join fetches entire object as null ?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi do u know the reasoning behind why inner join fetched entire null object whereas the Left join worked for you ?

Comment: @humbleCodes the inner join keeps only records where the inner join conditions are met. left join keeps all the records on the left side of the join.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is something completely different, because using a left outer join solves the problem you describe.

Change your query to:

```
select new com.core.data.category.CategoryDto(c.id,c.code,c.externalCode,c.seoMeta, c.createdAt, c.updatedAt, p.code) 
FROM Category c
LEFT JOIN c.parent p
WHERE c.code = :code
```

I created a [reproducer demonstrating that an outer join fixes the problem](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow/tree/main/jpa/constructor-expression-with-nested-reference).

The relevant code:

```java
@Entity
class SomeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String name;

    @ManyToOne
    SomeEntity parent;
}
```

```
public class Dto {

    final String name;
    final String parentName;

    public Dto(String name, String parentName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parentName = parentName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " - " + parentName;
    }
}
```

```
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeEntity, Long> {

    @Query("select new de.schauderhaft.de.constructorexpressionwithnestedreference.Dto(e.name, p.name) " +
            "from SomeEntity e " +
            "left join e.parent p")
    List<Dto> findDto();

    @Query("select new de.schauderhaft.de.constructorexpressionwithnestedreference.Dto(e.name, e.parent.name) " +
            "from SomeEntity e")
    List<Dto> findDtoInnerJoin();

    @Query("select e from SomeEntity e")
    List<SomeEntity> findEntities();
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
class ConstructorExpressionWithNestedReferenceApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    SomeEntityRepository ents;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void testDtos() {

        createEnts();

        assertThat(ents.findDto()).extracting(Dto::toString).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("ents name - parents name", "parents name - null");

    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void testDtosInnerJoin() {

        createEnts();

        assertThat(ents.findDtoInnerJoin()).extracting(Dto::toString).containsExactly("ents name - parents name");

    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void testEntities() {

        createEnts();

        assertThat(ents.findEntities()).extracting(e -> e.name).containsExactlyInAnyOrder("ents name", "parents name");

    }

    private void createEnts() {

        SomeEntity ent = new SomeEntity();
        ent.name = "ents name";
        ent.parent = new SomeEntity();
        ent.parent.name = "parents name";


        ents.saveAll(asList(ent, ent.parent));
    }

}
```

Comment: My issue was not looking at my query closely. I was not using left join but simple join :)